# How to set a cookie container in web browser control in windows phone 7 app development?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am developing an app in windows SDK 7.0. I am trying to set cookies in web browser control to maintain/validate session. But i am not able to set cookies in web browser control. Please help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have tried to pass the cookies through web_view.Navigate(uri,null,"Cookie:"+Cookie) method, but it doesn't work..than I tried InternetSetCookieEx of wininet.dll by DllImport utility..but it doesn't work either...

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, does anything happen? e.g. do you receive an error message?